# Why isn't my SynchronizationContext.Current.Send working sometimes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I'm working on an XMPP messaging application and firing off an event when a user has successfully logged in. The event that subscribes to it closes the logging in form and opens the main form. Simple stuff - except I have to use a SynchronizationContext to access the login form's Close() Method.

Here's how it works :

```
private SynchronizationContext syncContext; //Global SynchronizationContext
```

Inside the login form's constructor

```
InitializeComponent();

//set to current after initialization
syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

//subscribe to the event
EventAggregator.GetEvent<ContactListReadyEvent>().Subscribe(LoginResultHandler);
```

And finally the function that runs when the ContactListReadyEvent is fired

```
private void LoginResultHandler(ContactListReadyEventObject result)
{
    // send to UI thread
    syncContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate
    {
        EventAggregator.GetEvent<ContactListReadyEvent>).Unsubscribe(LoginResultHandler);
        mainFrm.Show();
        mainFrm.Focus();

        this.Close();
    }), null);
}
```

This code all runs perfectly... most of the time. But every once in a while the login form will freeze.

I set up some logging to find out where, and it gets inside the `LoginResultHandler`, but never runs inside `syncContext.Send`. I'm wondering if this is because I should be using `syncContext.Post`, or if I should be using a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` instead of a `SynchronizationContext`.

I know this isn't much information to work off of, some other information that might be useful is that this event is being subscribed to in other areas that are using that mainFrm - but when the login form freezes its because the `syncContext.send` never runs anything, like it's stuck waiting for something to happen before it runs.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: all you need is to show login form and if user presses login show the main form else cancel it?

Comment: Yes - and close the login form.

If I run the code w/o syncContext I will get an exception about the loginform close function trying to be called from another thread.

Comment: Are you `Wait`ing on something in the UI thread after event is fired?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything else. in your main form in your constructor and before initializecomponent do this. In your login form you can set the dialog result = ok if your presses ok or if he chooses to cancel you can set dialogresult = cancel.

```
frmLogin login = new frmLogin();
if(login.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
  this.Close();

InitializeComponent() //of your main form
```

Comment: I need the syncContext - this is happening in another area as well which also needs a syncContext and is also listening to the same event(I probably should have included that in the question, I'll update that now), I'm trying to solve both problems at once. It isn't as simple as using dialog result (what if the user presses OK but has the wrong password, or what if the contact list cant be retrieved or there is no internet connection). It must be closed after.

Comment: You can handle all your alternate scenarios for login on your login form. Like on ok you can send call to login and if succeeds you close with dialogresult.ok else show user a message that login failed.